# Can service workers detect fetch calls made inside an extension's content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

Inside a chrome extension, can `fetch` requests made by a content script (isolated world) be intercepted by the main website's service worker?

Comment: No, according to my tests. Even if the URL is controlled by the SW, which may be considered a bug, I guess.